# JavaScript: regex for replacing double curly quotes fails when single ones are present

Tags: javascript, regex

**Input:**

```
"Hello."
"'I'm not.'"
```

**Regex:**

```
/"\b/g // opening quote 
/"\B/g // closing quote
```

**Output:**

```
“Hello.”

”&#39;I&#39;m not.&#39;”
```

As you can see, the regex works OK when it's just a word. The problem arises when the word is surrounded by single quotes. Not sure what's the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Putting a word boundary inside a lookaround is useless since it is a zero-width assertion. if you want to negate it, use `\B`

Comment: It's because single quotes aren't a word boundary, so the opening quote isn't matching, and the closing quote is.  You'll need to rethink the approach to not use boundaries.  Perhaps using the `^` and `$` anchors instead, depending on the actual use case.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You mean using like `"\B` and `\B"` instead?

Comment: My notice was general and is not particularly related to the actual problem: `(?=\b)` is the same as `\b`, `(?!\b)` is the same as `\B`

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Oh, you're right, thanks.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte but the lookaround would be necessary if I did something like this? `(?=\b|')`

Comment: Yes, it is possible to write this, and it can be more handy than: `(?:\b|(?='))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to build the regex on the something-followedBy-notSomething-folowedBy-something approach. So it may look like below:

```js
var input = "\"'I'm not.'\" - said Marry.";
var rex = /"([^"]+)"/g
alert(input.replace(rex, '&#39;$1&#39;'))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yT6vR9/2)

Comment: But I think in this case the word inside the quotes is being matched? In my case, the word isn't being matched only the quotation marks.